# How to create an event that shows a random image from array to XAML Image

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on a simple UWP C# game and had some issues. I created an Assets folder and filled it with 5 images (0-4.png). I created a class named 'diamond' with this function:

```
public void insertimage()    
{    
  for (int i = 0; i <= diamond.Length -1; i++)
  {
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/{i}.png"));
    diamond[i] = img;    
  }    
}
```

Now I have an array with 5 images. I created a button on the grid and an IMAGE box.
I want that click event to show a random image from the array in the IMAGE box.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the random image in your image box when you get the random image? In addition, can you show your image box?

Comment: can you explain your question ? i have a empty image box located on the grid. i have an array with 5 images inside. when i click on a button i want one of the 5 images to be shown in the image box.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to use the [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) class.

You can then generate a random number with the `Random.next` function

Comment: thank you ! i did have a random class, my problem is the syntax that show the image in the image box after button click.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the image in the image box, you only need to save the BitmapImage into the diamond array. Then when you click the button and get the random index, put the BitmapImage which corresponds to the index to the Source of your image box. For example:

.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="myImage" Width="100" Height="100"></Image>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">click</Button>
<Grid>
```

.cs:

```
public void insertimage()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= diamond.Length -1; i++)
    {
         BitmapImage bitImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"ms- 
                                              appx:///Assets/{i}.png"));
         diamond[i] = bitImg;
    }

}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //the index is your random index
    BitmapImage pImg = diamond[randomIndex];
    myImage.Source = pImg;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer ! but i have 2 Errors. when i write diamond [i] = bitimg ; i have an error : "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image"    and in the click button in this line BitmapImage pImg = diamonds.diamond[i]; - i have this error :  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage. Home it is clear enough. thank you !

Comment: This error means the type mismatch. When you create the diamond, its element type should be set to BitmapImage. For example: you should create `List<BitmapImage> diamod = new List<BitmapImage>();` instead of `List<Image> diamod = new List<Image>();`